# RedirectMatch 301 remove query string / URL Parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

i need a Solution for the google search console error links and RedirectMatch 301 remove query string / URL Parameters in my htaccess:

**Google Search Console Links:**

```
https://www.domain.de/?main_page=index&zenid=umf5etlrmr4blnuiq0e4jsp6l2&cPath=15_326&sort=20a&alpha_filter_id=68

https://www.domain.de/index.php?main_page=product_reviews_write&products_id=9985&cPath=5_380&number_of_uploads=0

https://www.domain.de/?main_page=index&cPath=46_47&sort=20a&alpha_filter_id=70

https://www.domain.de/?currency=USD&main_page=products_new&disp_order=7&page=141

https://www.domain.de/?main_page=index&zenid=mj6nsb9r53goiu6e13nb80tfq7&cPath=1_160&sort=20a&alpha_filter_id=70

https://www.domain.de/?currency=USD&main_page=index&cPath=3_137

https://www.domain.de/?main_page=index&cPath=46_76&sort=20a&alpha_filter_id=84

https://www.domain.de/?main_page=index&cPath=5_6&sort=20a&alpha_filter_id=85

https://www.domain.de/index.php?main_page=index
```

And many more.

I test this way in the htaccess, but it didn't work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?main_page*$ https://www.domain.de/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?main_page\=$ https://www.domain.de/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?main_page?$ https://www.domain.de/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Both RedirectMatch and RewriteRule match against the _path_ component of the URL only. And your RewriteCond tries to match a query string that consists of _only_ `main_page` and nothing else.

Comment: ah okay, what is the right way?

Comment: If you just want to match any query string that contains `main_page` anywhere - then don't anchor the RewriteCond pattern at the start and end. And the path to match in the RewriteRule for just the root, would be just an empty one, so `^$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following generic rule to remove query strings

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(main_page|currency) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding one more approach of htaccess rules here, written as per shown samples. Using Apache's `THE_REQUEST` variable here.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(?:index\.php)?/?(?:\?(?:main_page|currency))?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

***OR*** as an alternative use following code(using `QSD` flag here to remove query string):

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(?:index\.php)?/?(?:\?(?:main_page|currency))?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]
```